# How to adjust webpage view using wkwebview

Tags: wkwebview, swift5

I am loading a url to wkwebview and i want to keep it from viewing a side of the webpage like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qStJ1C_rrcjobSuorgPeLTkHZc82oUV4/view?usp=sharing

instead of

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G05f6UVolmQCqdqKdJ0UFBBA6LVDI-BN/view?usp=sharing

Scrollview is already false and bounces are false too. Can someone help me

Thanks!

I have already tried using the scrollview and bounces parameters but the wkwebview still moves to the left exposing the blue part shown in the images. I want to display the webpage as shown in the first image so that its, for lack of a better word, view is locked as displayed. I'm not sure if I am explaining myself good, but let me know if I need to explain. I have added a video below showing what I want to know how to do.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uErGQlB1HKLU7px49UtGbsX9nOYqa3FN/view?usp=sharing

import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewControllerWebKit: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

```
var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {


    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/communities/space-weather-enthusiasts")


   let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}}
```

As shown in the photos and video, I don't know how to keep it from moving so it doesn't show the blue side which is part of the webpage.

Comment: here are the pics since it is not showing:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the page from being scrolled to the side, the width in the html that you are showing should be equal to device-width. you can do so by defining the [viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). The thing is that your page has the blue bar in the right so either way I think you have to show it.
This solution will stop the scrolling behavior, but the bar will still be showing as it is part of the page.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let jscript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width');  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: jscript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    let wkUController = WKUserContentController()
    wkUController.addUserScript(userScript)
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.userContentController = wkUController


    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView

    webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/communities/space-weather-enthusiasts")

    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}
```

Hope this could help.